# How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, amsmath

Is there a way to force a line break inside a math mode text?

My example:

```
\[
  \underbrace{....}_\text{Some long text that should be multiline}
\]
```

Trying

```
\text{Some long text that\\ should be multiline}
```

Didn't do the trick.

Comment: While it is not an answer, I thought you might like to know why `\\` fails inside `\text`. If you look through the code, `\text` will insert an `\hbox` for the content when in math mode. TeX sets `\hbox` material in a mode where paragraphs are ignored, so there will never be a break _inside_ the argument of the `\text` macro.

Comment: Is there a reasonable solution in Plain TeX?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can use the `\substack` command, from the `amsmath` package, just like `\text`.

```
\[
  \underbrace{...}_{\substack{\text{Some long text that} \\ \text{should be multiline}}}
\]
```

The output:

[image: Example of LaTeX output]

Comment: Why do you have 3 backslashes where the ... nvm, I see now.  I feel this answer would be better with some spacing for readability.  Also, I believe the answer would be improved if it were pointed out that `\substack` was designed for this very purpose. (It was right?)

Answer (score 45):

- `\substack`, mentioned by Carsten, probably fits best to your `\underbrace` because of the centered alignment.
- `subarray` is similar but offers customizable alignment:

Example:

```
\[
 \underbrace{....}_{\begin{subarray}{l}\text{Some  long text that}\\
    \text{should be multiline}\end{subarray}}
\]
```

- `\parbox` also works in math mode. You could use a font size command inside.

Answer (score 29):

Another possibility:

```
\[
 \underbrace{some equation}_{\text{Some long text that}\atop\text{should be multilined}}
\]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myText[1]{\text{\scriptsize\tabular[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\endtabular}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \underbrace{....}_\myText{Some long text that\\ should be multiline}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It can be centered by replacing the `@{}l@{}` with `@{}c@{}`

Answer (score 4):

A simple `\parbox` with a certain width should also do.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}   % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \[
    \underbrace{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}_{\text{\parbox{10em}{Some text that should be multi-lined}}}
  \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: If you remove the `\text` it sure does. At least in [my context](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287068/42315). @d555

Answer (score 3):

One more, for a very long text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\mysum}
\settowidth{\mysum}{$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9$}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9}_{
\begin{minipage}{\mysum}\lipsum[2]\end{minipage}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```