# How do I insert a new line within a subscript block?

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to divide up the content under a summation into different lines to no avail.

```
\sum\limits_{some~really~really~ \\ really~really~really~ \\ long~string}
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: `substack` from `amsmath`- there's a duplicate somehwhere

Comment: I think it's this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines

Comment: Or is it this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-write-multiple-lines-in-a-subscript/7504#7504 ?