# Big lower limit on an integral

Tags: math-mode

I would like to write an integral with a big lower limit. I am using

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \[\int\limits_{\mbox{This is a\\ large limit}}xdx\]
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

How can I split this rahter big limit?
One idea would be to write it as a matrix but I supposse there must an easiest way.

Comment: `\substack` of the `amsmath` package is your friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7503/5764).