# How to break line of subscript under min?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

```
$$
\min_{c^{(1)}, c^{(2)}, \cdots, c^{(m)}; \\ \mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_K}
\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m \left\lVert \vec{x}^{(i)} - \mu_{c^{(i)}} \right\rVert
$$
```

The `\\` does not seem to do the trick? How?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: this looks like a duplicate of [How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7503)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `\substack`:

[image]

### Notes:

- [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\min_{\substack{c^{(1)}, c^{(2)}, \cdots, c^{(m)}; \\ \mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_K}}
\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m \left\lVert \vec{x}^{(i)} - \mu_{c^{(i)}} \right\rVert
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `\,` is definitely needed before `\frac{1}{m}` and probably also in `\vec{x}^{\,(i)}`; I'm almost certain that `\left` and `\right` can (should) be omitted; possibly `\bigl\lVert` and `\bigr\rVert` could be used. Finally, `\cdots` should be `\dots`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative version, without `\substack`, but with some additional work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[
\min_{\begin{array}{c}\scriptstyle c^{(1)}, c^{(2)}, \cdots, c^{(m)}; \\[-4pt]
\scriptstyle \mu_1, \mu_2, \cdots, \mu_K
\end{array}
}
\frac{1}{m}
\sum_{i=1}^m \left\lVert \vec{x}^{(i)} - \mu_{c^{(i)}} \right\rVert
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also recommend replacing `\cdots` by `\ldots` or `\dots`.