# How can print this type of summation?

Tags: code

I am a new latex users and in a report must print this type of summation

[image]

What is the latex code

Thanks to Steven B. Segletes I have obtained this result:

[image]

I need to reduce the space highlighted

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-write-multiple-lines-in-a-subscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{0\le x<100\\x\in\mathbb{Z}}} f(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To keep the substack from affecting the function offset, one can use `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\mathclap{\substack{0\le x<100\\x\in\mathbb{Z}}}} f(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity what is the difference between \begin{equation} \end{equation} and \[ \]????

Comment: @LucaAngelino The use of `\[...\]` does not number the equation, whereas `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` does.  Vertical spacing around the equation may also be slightly different.

Comment: also \begin{equation*}...\end{equation*} don't number the equation

Comment: @LucaAngelino `equation*` requires the `amsmath` package, whereas `\[...\]` does not.  Of course, for this problem, `amsmath` is needed for the `\substack`.

Comment: can I also reduce the space between the summation and the function?????

Comment: @LucaAngelino  See second version of answer.