# How to stack/insert line breaks between minimization arguments beneath the min symbol?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, math-operators, stacking-symbols

I tried

`$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m, \\ y \in \mathbb{R}^n}$`

but `\\` doesn't create a line-break in this setting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate long math text under sum symbol into different lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12344/separate-long-math-text-under-sum-symbol-into-different-lines) It's about sums, not limits, but the solution is the same.

Comment: See also [How can I write multiple lines in a subscript?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7503/82917).

Comment: The first link doesn't answer the question. the second one does: `\substack{}`

Comment: The accepted answer in first link suggests `\substack` too `:-)`

Comment: oh right didn't scroll down