# How to write subscript on multiple lines in an align* environment?

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, line-breaking

I'm writing `\max_{some very long subscript} = f(x)` within an `\begin{align*} \end{align*}` environment. The subscript is very long, so I want to write it on multiple lines under `max`.

I looked into [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/how-can-i-write-multiple-lines-in-a-subscript) post here, but I could not get it to work in the `align*` environment.

```
\begin{align*}
max_{some very long subscript} &= f(x)\\
max_{some other very long subscript} &= g(x)
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethink like this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \max_{\substack{\text{some very}\mathstrut \\ \text{long subscript} }} & = f(x) \\
  \max_{\substack{\text{some other}\mathstrut \\ \text{very long subscript} }} & = g(x)   
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: *I have not your minimal working example*.

Comment: Yes, something like that. But embedding it in the `align*` environment seems to have issues, i.e., `\begin{align*}
    \[\max_{\substack{\\ \text{some very} \\ \text{long subscript} }} = f(x)\]
\end{align*}` does not work for me. Also added a toy example to my original post.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Devon - Don't embed `\[` and `\]` in an `align*` environment.