# How can I have multiple lines for the underbrace label?

Tags: math-mode, underbrace

How can I have multiple lines for the underbrace label?

```
--\/--
 A cost
 [A]
```

---

This is a some dummy equation to show what I already have.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{color, etoolbox, lipsum, mathtools, geometry}
\usepackage{cuted, textcomp, setspace, longtable, tabularx, array}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    {
            \begin{equation}
                c()=
                \begin{cases}
                    \underbrace{A'^{hr} \cdot Z^{\text{g}}}_{\textsubscript{A\ cost}}
                    + \underbrace{f(\Upsilon'^{hr}) \cdot ~'^{\text{get}} \cdot F^{ca}}_{\textsubscript{B\ cost}}
                    + \underbrace{B'^{\text{get}} \cdot F^{t}}_{\textsubscript{C\ cost}}
                    \right) & \text{if}\ B'^{\text{r}}=0 \\
                    1       & \text{otherwise.}
                \end{cases}
            \end{equation}
        }\bigskip]
\end{document}
```

With following output:

[image]

Wanted output, where under `A cost` there is `[A]` | under `B cost` there is `[B]` | under `C cost` there is `[C]`:
[image]

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7503/263192 help?

Comment: Yes ` \\ ` did not helped but `\atop\text{}`help to solve the issue I was having

Comment: Unrelated, note that `\text` should not be used for things like `\text{get}` etc. It does not do what you might think (write stuff upright, try addit `\itshape` before `\begin{equation}`). Use `\textrm` or `\mathrm` instead.

Comment: @daleif Thanks I was lost in the formats :-) `text{}` seemed more compact than `mathrm` thats why I used it. Should I do `\text{\itshape get }}` or just `\atop\mathrm{}`? Simple example would be appreciated. Is it also ok to use `\textsubscript{}` for the text under the underbrace

Comment: As I mentioned use `\mathrm` or `\textrm` instead of `\text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `array` environment. By the way some codes are improved and some mistake are revised.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{color, etoolbox, lipsum, mathtools, geometry}
\usepackage{cuted, textcomp, setspace, longtable, tabularx, array}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    {
            \begin{equation}
                c()=
                \begin{cases}
                    \underbrace{A'^{\mathrm{hr}} \cdot Z^{\mathrm{g}}}_{\begin{array}{c}A\text{ cost}\\[-0.5ex] [\mathbf{A}]\end{array}}
                    + \underbrace{f(\Upsilon'^{\mathrm{hr}}) \cdot ~'^{\mathrm{get}} \cdot F^\mathrm{ca}}_{\begin{array}{c}B\text{ cost}\\[-0.5ex] [\mathbf{B}]\end{array}}
                    + \underbrace{B'^{\mathrm{get}} \cdot F^{\mathrm{t}}}_{\begin{array}{c}C\text{ cost}\\[-0.5ex] [\mathbf{C}]\end{array}}
                    & \text{if}\ B'^{\mathrm{r}}=0; \\
                    1       & \text{otherwise.}
                \end{cases}
            \end{equation}
        }\bigskip]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I appreciated you revision. Should I convert `{hr}` into `{\mathrm{hr}}` as well? Is it possible to make space between `[A] [B] [C]` and 1 smaller

Comment: Will this equation fit inside the width of a single column in a two-column document?

Comment: @alper If hr and g are the same type, then hr should be in mathrm too. Adding more spaces between [A] and 1 isn’t advised otherwise it will be confufused.

Comment: @Mico It’s a new question.

Comment: @M.Logic got it, I thought you left `{hr}` without `mathrm{}`  in purpose since it was 2 characters; so I can convert them into `{\mathrm{hr}}` without a problem

Answer (score 5):

I sugggest you use `\substack` macros to create compactly spaced two-row items below each `\underbrace`.

Since you're dealing with a twocolumn layout, I think it's also necessary to insert an extra line break for the first case.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{color, etoolbox, lipsum, mathtools, geometry}
%\usepackage{cuted, textcomp, setspace, longtable, tabularx, array}
\usepackage{mathtools,geometry}
\begin{document}
\begingroup % limit scope of next instruction
\small
\begin{equation}
c()=
\begin{dcases*}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
  \underbrace{A^{\prime hr} Z^{\mathrm{g}}\mathstrut}_{%
        \substack{\text{A cost} \\ [\mathbf{A}]}}
&+ \underbrace{f(\Upsilon^{\prime hr}) ~^{\prime \mathrm{get}} F^{ca}}_{%
        \substack{\text{B cost} \\ [\mathbf{B}]}} \\
&+ \underbrace{B^{\prime \mathrm{get}} F^{t}}_{%
        \substack{\text{C cost} \\ [\mathbf{C}]}}
 \end{aligned} 
    & if $B^{\prime \mathrm{r}}=0$ \\
  1 & otherwise.
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this golden approach. Could I switch 1 and the upper equation? I am not that could also help to make it more compact or advices

Comment: @alper - Please clarify what you mean by "switch 1 and the upper equation". Do you maybe ask how to place the equation number on the first line?

Comment: Example output is illustrated https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/f377410c93dc870b76ae895e1b6351df?permalink_comment_id=4157321#gistcomment-4157321. Just `1 otherwise` moved into first line